# How do I make a form refresh whenever Database is updated?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database (table) on Microsoft Access that's constantly updating from python and I have a form displaying Fields from that table. How do I make a form update (refresh) automatically when data is added to the table it's reading from?

I've set a button that runs Me.Requery when pressed thus refreshing the Form and getting the new data, but I want for to update/refresh automatically. On Data change (Form_datachange) doesn't work (don't know why).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, I'm using Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think you can run a macro to requery your form when the table updates due to the restrictions on data macros.

However, you can put your requery logic in the form’s OnTimer event and set it to run at a desired interval (e.g. 5000 ms which is 5 seconds)